Cannot Register Slash Commands while Building my Discord Bot
I have trying my hands out in building my own Discord Bot. I have tuned it to reply on any message from the user. I have built it entirely by reading the documentation on discord.js. The reply thing is working perfectly. However, as per the code in the documentation to register a slash command it's not working with me:-(
*I have refreshed and pasted the TOKEN in my code and the CLIENT_ID too.
edit:- It's not showing any error on the console as well.
//Here is my Code
import { REST, Routes } from 'discord.js';
const TOKEN = '**********************************';
const CLIENT_ID = '************';

const commands = [
  {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Replies with Pong!',
  },
];

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(TOKEN);

try {
  console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

  await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID), { body: commands });

  console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}


Discord allows users to register only 200 application commands per day.
Instead of registering commands globally with
await rest.put(
      Routes.applicationCommands(
        CLIENT_ID,
      ),
      {
        body: commands,
      }
    );

You should register them locally on your test guild using its id
await rest.put(
      Routes.applicationGuildCommands(
        CLIENT_ID,
        GUILD_ID
      ),
      {
        body: commands,
      }
    );

Keep in mind that you may have to wait a day until you can register commands again.
